# Are student IDs unique across domains?

Tags: google-classroom

I am integrating my app with google classroom. I will have a firebase db with the student progress information. The app is used by multiple schools. I am wondering if I can use the student id from classroom as a unique and searchable identifier for a student, so, I don't have to access their email, or, is it preferable to store their email?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the id returned is the same one as for oauth. I am assuming that's unique across google logins whether from different school domains.